# Counting matrices over a finite field.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, finite-fields

Let $ \mathcal{M}^{k \times n} = \{ A \in \mathbb{F}_q^{k \times n} \mid A \text{ is full rank and every } \; k \times k \; \text{submatrix of }\; A \;\text{is invertible}\}$. I want to know $|\mathcal{M}^{k \times n}| $. I know that since $\mathcal{M}^{k \times n}$ is subset of the full rank matrices then the number I'm looking for is less than $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots (q^n-q^{k-1})$ (the number of full rank matrices) but if you make the count for $ k=1$ this seems to be false:

When $ k=1$ every sub matrix having determinant distinct to zero is equivalent to being full rank, so one has to count only the number of vectors with non zero entries: $ (q^n-1)^n > q^n-1$.

I know that I might be wrong but I can't see how

Thank you all in advance

**Edit**
I forgot to add that $n>k $, this will implie that in $k=1 $ being full rank only means not to be the zero vector i.e we are only looking for the vectors with non zero entries (there are $ (q^n-1)^n > q^n-1$ many of them ) but hte equivalence I state does not holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two methods:

- *Blind computation:* $A$ has maximal rank $k$ iff any one $k\times k$ submatrix is invertible. So it's enough to ask that every $k\times k$ submatrix is invertible. Break $A$ into the top $k\times k$ box and the bottom $(n-k)\times k$ rectangle. There are 
  $$(q^k-1)(q^k-q)\cdots(q^k-q^{k-1})$$
  ways of filling in the top box invertibly, as you said.

  What about the next row? That row vector $v$ must lie outside all the $k-1$ dimensional spaces $\Pi_1,...,\Pi_k\subseteq V$ spanned by row vectors of the top box. Thus there are 
  $$q^k-1- |\Pi_1\cup \cdots \cup \Pi_k|$$
  possible $v$'s. We compute using inclusion-exclusion
  $$|\Pi_1\cup \cdots \cup \Pi_k|=k|\Pi_1|-\binom{k}{2}|\Pi_1\cap \Pi_2|+\cdots \pm |\Pi_1\cap \cdots \cap \Pi_k|$$
  Each intersection has dimension one less than the last, so 
  $$|\Pi_1\cup \cdots \cup \Pi_k|=kq^{k-1}-\binom{k}{2}q^{k-2}+\cdots \pm q^0=(-q+1)^k=q^k-(q-1)^k$$
  and there are this many chocies for $v$:
  $$(q-1)^k-1$$

  What about the next row after that? There are now $k+1$ spaces $\Pi_1,...,\Pi_{k+1}\subseteq V$ to avoid, and
  $$|\Pi_1\cup \cdots \cup \Pi_{k+1}|=(k+1)q^{k-1}-\binom{k}{2}q^{k-2}+\cdots \pm \binom{k+1}{1}q^0$$
  is 
  $$\frac{1}{q}\left(q^{k+1}-(q-1)^{k+1}+(-1)^{k+1}\right)$$
  And these are the number of choices for the row vector:
  $$\frac{1}{q}\left((q-1)^{k+1}-(-1)^{k+1}\right)-1$$

  The general term is 
  $$\alpha_{m+1}=\frac{1}{q^m}\left((q-1)^{k+m} \text{ with the last }m\text{ summands cut off }\right)-1$$
  and the number of such matrices is thus
  $$(q^k-1)(q^k-q)\cdots (q^k-q^{k-1}) \  \alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_{n-k}$$
- *Computation:* Let $V,W$ have dimensions $k$ and $n$, and $\alpha: V\to W$ be a linear map between them. Pick a basis $e_1,...,e_n$ of $W$. Then the matrix of $\alpha$ satisfies your property iff 
  $$V\stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow}W\stackrel{\pi_i}{\longrightarrow}W_i$$
  is invertible for each $W_i\subseteq W$ generated by some $k$ of the $e_i$, and $\pi_i$ is the projection using the basis. Equivalently, $\pi_i\cdot \alpha$ is injective, i.e.
  $$\text{im }\alpha \ \cap \ \ker \pi_i \ = \ 0.$$

  We now count how many possible $\alpha$ there are by looking how it acts on a basis $v_1,...,v_k$ of $V$. First, what are the conditions on $\alpha(v_1)$? The above gives
  $$\alpha(v_1) \ \not \in \ \ker \pi_1 \cup \ker \pi_2 \cup \cdots \ \ \ = \Omega$$
  Then there are $q^n-|\Omega|$ choices for $\alpha(v_1)$.

  What about $\alpha(v_2)$? Not only $\alpha(v_2)\not \in \Omega$, but also $\alpha(av_1+bv_2)\not \in \Omega$, which is equivalent to $\alpha(v_2)\not \in \Omega +a\alpha(v_1)$ for all $a$. Now, 
  $$|\{ \Omega +a\alpha(v_1) : a \in \mathbb{F}_q\}\ = \ q|\Omega|$$
  so there are $q|\Omega|$ choices for $\alpha(v_2)$.

  Similarly, having chosen $\alpha(v_1),...,\alpha(v_r)$, there are $q^r|\Omega|$ choices for $\alpha(v_{r+1})$. Thus in total, there are
  $$q^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}} |\Omega|^k$$ 
  possible such $\alpha$.

The second method is more useful in smaller dimensions, because $\Omega$, the union of the $n-k$ dimensional standard hyperplanes in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$, has $|\Omega|$ easily computible. In general I think it will be as much of a mess as the first method.

Comment: Why did you take the $\Pi_i $ separatedley instead of taking the single space generated by all of the rows?  Because the next row is going to be independent of the other rows if and only of it is not in the space generated by them, isn't it?

Comment: I already have a $k\times k$ invertible matrix $M$, and I want to put a row $v$ on the bottom so that any $k\times k$ submatrix of that is invertible. To check this one only needs to check submatrices containing the row $v$. Then there are $k$ choices of the $k-1$ other rows you choose, each of which gives a $\Pi_i$. That $k\times k$ submatrix is invertible iff $v\not \in \Pi_i$.